# Execute ADB command from Java program

Tags: java, process, adb

The program I'm working on uses ADB (Android Debug Bridge) to send files to my phone:

```
for (String s : files)
    String cmd = "adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF push " + s + " /mnt/sdcard/" + s;
    try {
        InputStream is = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd).getInputStream();
        while (is.read() != -1) {}
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want the program to wait until ADB finished the transmission, but ADB runs as a daemon and therefore never finishes. But the program continues immideately and somehow the files aren't sent to my phone (no exceptions in log). When I run the command from console, it's working without problems.

What am I doing wrong? How do I send files via ADB correctly?

NOTE: the `is.read() == -1` won't work, because the ADB daemon writes *all output* to the system standard output. I've tried forwarding it into a textfile. It stayed empty and the output was still written to the terminal instead

**EDIT**: Reading the ErrorStream of the ADB process returned the adb help for each `adb push`-command. Again: The *exact* commands (copied from Eclipse console) work in a terminal

**EDIT 2**: Using a ProcessBuilder instead of `RUntime.getRuntime.exec()` resulted in the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb -s 0123456789ABCDEF push "inputfile "outputfile""": error=2, File or directory not found
```

at the ProcessBuilder's `start()`-method
The same happens when using an absolute path for ADB (`/usr/bin/adb`). The inputfile and outputfile Strings are also absolute paths, like `/home/sebastian/testfile` and definitely exist. When running the commands from terminal (string "cmd" printed, copy&paste), evreything still works fine.

Comment: Your last observation is your best lead currently. Just to be sure, but you do not have special characters in the file names. And you are sure to pick up the same adb executable in the shell as well as in your program. Does the adb error output only contain the general help or something specific it does not like?

Comment: Both just uses "adb", which refers to `/usr/bin/adb`. The only special char is an underscore, which shouldn't cause any problems. And It's the exact same output as `adb help` in the error log. The output of the process (`getInputStream()`) is empty.

Comment: At the end of the ADB help in the output of my program there's a \uFFFF character. Is this normal? The `adb help` command in console forwarded doesn't

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally got it working:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "-s", "0123456789ABCDEF", "push", inputfile, outputfile);
Process pc = pb.start();
pc.waitFor();
System.out.println("Done");
```

I don't know what problems `ProcessBuilder` has with spaces in a string, but finally, it's working...

Comment: Definitely ProcessBuilder doesn't handle correctly a String with spaces, I'm passing an ArrayList and it's working correctly now, thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 11):

I've solved in this way:

```
public class Utils {
    private static final String[] WIN_RUNTIME = { "cmd.exe", "/C" };
    private static final String[] OS_LINUX_RUNTIME = { "/bin/bash", "-l", "-c" };

    private Utils() {
    }

    private static <T> T[] concat(T[] first, T[] second) {
        T[] result = Arrays.copyOf(first, first.length + second.length);
        System.arraycopy(second, 0, result, first.length, second.length);
        return result;
    }

    public static List<String> runProcess(boolean isWin, String... command) {
        System.out.print("command to run: ");
        for (String s : command) {
            System.out.print(s);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
        String[] allCommand = null;
        try {
            if (isWin) {
                allCommand = concat(WIN_RUNTIME, command);
            } else {
                allCommand = concat(OS_LINUX_RUNTIME, command);
            }
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(allCommand);
            pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String _temp = null;
            List<String> line = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((_temp = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("temp line: " + _temp);
                line.add(_temp);
            }
            System.out.println("result after command: " + line);
            return line;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't need env variables in your .bash_profile cut "-l" parameter.

I have a Mac but it should work on Linux also.

Comment: check new edited answer, it works on old Win OS, not tested yet on Win8

Comment: Thanks for your effort. However, on Win8 (maybe also on old Win OS?), the compiler complains about the statement `Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(ADBExecutor.WIN_RUNTIME, "adb devices").start();`: `The constructor ProcessBuilder(String[], String) is undefined`. Therefore, I edit it to `Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/C", this.adb_directory, "devices").start();` and it works. Please check it out.

Comment: Yes, you're right ! I've edited againg and put same implementation I'm using in my codebase

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void adbpush() {
        System.out.println("adb push....");
        String[] aCommand = new String[] { adbPath, "push", inputFile(String),OutputDirectory };
        try {
            // Process process = new ProcessBuilder(aCommand).start();
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(aCommand);
            process.waitFor(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            System.out.println("file pushed");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to give full path for ADB execution: like this `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb devices`

This is the full code you can use:

```
String cmd = "$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb devices";
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
if (Config.osName.contains("Windows"))
    processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", cmd);
else
    processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", cmd);

Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
string cmd = "/system/bin/input keyevent 23\n";
os.writeBytes(cmd);
```

the phone must be rooted. here I have executed adb command "input keyevent 23". remember when you execute adb command through su you does not need to add "adb shell input keyevent 23"