# How to get the list of process running in android device using Selendroid

Tags: android, selendroid

Can any one help me in getting the list of running process in Android using Selendroid?

Comment: Please add some more specific description to your question !

Comment: I need to test an application on android device. Here what i need to test is, I have a close button in my application and when i click on that button it close the application and the respective process gets  killed. Now i am able to click on close button but i don't know how to check the list of process running in android using Selendroid??To validate weather the process is running or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using ADB connection:

```java
driver.getAdbConnection().executeShellCommand("ps > file");
driver.getAdbConnection().executeShellCommand("pull file localfile");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...  

I am able to generate the file using ps command but i am unable to copy the file using the above given command   
driver.getAdbConnection().executeShellCommand("pull file localfile")...     

It throws system/bin/sh.pull not found..Can you please help me in copying the file from device to PC using selendroid?

Comment: I remember i have problem with that. I think i used for that native ADB in java.
You should look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922600/execute-adb-command-from-java-program