# Android push shell command on uiautomator

Tags: android, adb, ui-automation

I tried to use uiautomation to push mp3 in my device,so i use this code:

```
mDevice.executeShellCommand("push music\\testing.mp3 /sdcard/Music");
```

but after I run ,nothing happen,is there something wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

executeShellCommand executes a command **in** the device you're automating. It is the UiAutomator equivalent of "`adb shell <command>`". However, to push a file to such device, you should execute it in your local machine (where the file is), as the device knows nothing about it.

Automation frameworks such as Appium [already provide a simple function](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/files/push-file/) for pushing files, but I couldn't find anything similar for low level UiAutomator. Your simplest choice is to manually invoke adb push:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "-s", "DEVICE_UDID", "push", "music\\testing.mp3", "/sdcard/Music");
Process pc = pb.start();
pc.waitFor();
```

[(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922600/execute-adb-command-from-java-program)

Make sure to replace `DEVICE_UDID` with the identifier of your device (as shown in adb devices). Alternatively, if there is **only** one device connected to your computer, you can remove `"-s", "DEVICE_UDID"` from the command, it will assume your connected device as the target of your command.